# how to draw route between 2 points and export to kml?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps, kml

I have the lists of the 2 geo points that is the street and I want to draw it by these 2 geo points.

```
    long     lat        long     lat
1.  45.1406, 5.69213    45.1354, 5.69041
2.  45.237,  5.66205    45.2179, 5.67593
3.  45.2059, 5.70887    45.2017, 5.7154
4.  45.2086, 5.68668    45.1916, 5.70283
....
```

I want to draw it automatically one by one with these coordinates.

The result I wanted on google map is :

[image]

After I reverse that two coordinates, the result is :

[image]

But I don't want that. something I want after I reversed it is :

[image]

My problem is I always change it manually.

So, how can I draw and export it to kml?

**Note:** my data is not 4 or 10 rows, but I have 1500+ rows that why I need something to do with it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Kml doesn't do routing. From kml perspective you can easily create a placemark with geometry type linestring and stuff all coordinates in there if that is what you need but what you have in your 2nd screenshot is _not_ the reverse coordinates of the first. You moved them a tad to east from the N->S road to the S->N route. Are you looking for something that knows that the points you specified should be moved and where they should move to or ...?

Comment: I mean I want to get 2 points and extract it to 2 KML files. So, first KML is for A->B direction and second KML is for B->A direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need something to create your routes, which I can't tell if you're doing that manually or have some routing engine. KML lets you create travel paths, which are just collections Long/Lat/Elevation points. there's nothing inheritently in KML that does routing.